# Failed to import third-part non-bazel package with bazel 0.17.1 while using new_git_repository rule

Tags: bazel

My Workspace

```sh
cat WORKSPACE
```

```py
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository", "new_git_repository")

http_archive(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_go",
    urls = ["https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/releases/download/0.16.5/rules_go-0.16.5.tar.gz"],
    sha256 = "7be7dc01f1e0afdba6c8eb2b43d2fa01c743be1b9273ab1eaf6c233df078d705",
)

load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:def.bzl", "go_rules_dependencies", "go_register_toolchains")
go_rules_dependencies()
go_register_toolchains()

# ... rocksdb and etc

new_git_repository(
    name = "com_github_tecbot_gorocksdb",
    remote = "https://github.com/tecbot/gorocksdb.git",
    commit = "3e476152774442234f9a9f747386a48a1d82a515",
    build_file = "third-party/gorocksdb.BUILD",
)
```

and my gorocksdb.BUILD

```sh
cat third-party/gorocksdb.BUILD
```

```py
load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:def.bzl", "go_library")

go_library(
    name = "go_default_library",
    srcs = [
        "backup.go",
        "cache.go",
        "cf_handle.go",
        # ...
        "write_batch.go",
        "gorocksdb.c",
        "gorocksdb.h",
    ],
    importpath = "github.com/tecbot/gorocksdb",
    cgo = True,
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    cdeps = [
        "@com_github_facebook_rocksdb//:rocksdb",
    ],
)
```

I run bazel using [Bazel containers](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/bazel-container.html).

```sh
docker run -e USER=(id -u) -u=(id -u) -v $PWD:/src/workspace -v /tmp/build_output:/tmp/build_output -w /src/workspace l.gcr.io/google/bazel:0.17.1 --output_user_root=/tmp/build_output run --verbose_failures //:helloworld
```

And I got errors like

```
ERROR: /src/workspace/BUILD.bazel:3:1: no such package '@com_github_tecbot_gorocksdb//': Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/build_output/a08c2e4811c846650b733c6fc815a920/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl", line 160
        workspace_and_buildfile(ctx)
    File "/tmp/build_output/a08c2e4811c846650b733c6fc815a920/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/utils.bzl", line 60, in workspace_and_buildfile
        ctx.symlink(ctx.attr.build_file, "BUILD.bazel")
Not a regular file: /src/workspace/external/third-party/gorocksdb.BUILD and referenced by '//:helloworld'
```

I see the [docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#new_local_repository_args) of bazel, and found the description of `build_file` attr.

> String; optional
>
> A file to use as a BUILD file for this directory.
>   Either build_file or build_file_content must be specified.
>
> This attribute is a label relative to the main workspace. The file does not need to be named BUILD, but can be. (Something like BUILD.new-repo-name may work well for distinguishing it from the repository's actual BUILD files.)

It seems like that `third-party/gorocksdb.BUILD` is a correct relative path from WORKSPACE, and it works in some lower version bazel. I don't know why bazel try to find this file under `__workspace_dir__/external/`, I really not declare anything named external, is it a new feature in bazel and not documented?

I'm sure all other parts in my project is correct because when I copy the whole content of `gorocksdb.BUILD` and paste it with `build_file_content` attr, it works very well.

Comment: ![enter image description here]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54195855/failed-to-import-third-part-non-bazel-package-with-bazel-0-17-1-while-using-new/54200810#54200810https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmBm0.jpg)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54195855/failed-to-import-third-part-non-bazel-package-with-bazel-0-17-1-while-using-new/54200810#54200810![enter image description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54195855/-answer-bazel-package-with-bazel-0-17-1-while-using-new/54200810#54200810)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by removing the following line

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository", "new_git_repository")
```

The behavior of new_git_repository in bazel tools in bazel 0.17 is not the same as the builtin method.